# Except when trying to display ad

Tags: c#, exception, interop

I'm trying to display an advertisement when an event is called, using this code:

```
using Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI;
.
.
private InterstitialAd ad;
.
.
Interop.RequestInterstitialEvent += Interop_RequestInterstitialEvent;
Interop.ShowInterstitialEvent += Interop_ShowInterstitialEvent;
.
.
.
void Interop_RequestInterstitialEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  //When I want to recharge ad
    ad = new InterstitialAd();
    ad.RequestAd(AdType.Video, "d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab", "11389925");
}

void Interop_ShowInterstitialEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ // Show your ad only if it is charging
    if (ad.State == InterstitialAdState.Ready)
    {
        ad.Show();
    }
}
```

Displays the following error:
[image: Error]

Determine when to display the announcement shortly after the `Ready` the same it works:

```
void Interop_RequestInterstitialEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ad = new InterstitialAd();
    ad.RequestAd(AdType.Video, "d25517cb-12d4-4699-8bdc-52040c712cab", "11389925");
    ad.AdReady += ad_AdReady;
}

void ad_AdReady(object sender, object e)
{
    ad.Show();
}
```

But I want to display it only when I call `Interop_ShowInterstitialEvent`. How do I display it in that event?